# Clustering by fitting many linear SVMs and clustering their weight vectors?

Tags: time-series, clustering, svm

Let’s say I have a bunch of discrete sequence data, with each sequence belonging to some individual (there are ~1000 individuals and many more sequences). With a great deal of success, one can train a linear soft-margin SVM that includes some “bigram” and “history” features (among others) to predict the next outcome given a partial sequence.

A different SVM is trained for each individual on the subset of sequences they are responsible for.

If I wanted to cluster the individuals based on the tendencies that show up in the sequences, would it make sense to cluster the SVM weight vectors (or cluster the SVM parameters in some other way)? I am open to the idea that this is stupid or unlikely to be helpful. I am also open to the idea that there is a widely-used, better way of getting the result I want.

I guess more broadly, if you have many instances of the same model, each making predictions for an individual, does it make sense to cluster the individuals based on their model parameters? Even pointers towards vaguely related papers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Weight vectors are not *stable* and *not exhaustive*.

Don't forget you are talking about *support* vector machines, that try to minimize the number of data points with nonzero weight.

Vectors that are easy to classify tend to get 0 weight, difficult examples get chosen. For duplicates, only one is chosen. For large parts of your data set, the weoghts will always be zero!

Comment: Since this question is about linear SVMs, the weight vectors are probably primal weight vectors on the feature dimensions, not dual weight vectors on the instances....

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It seems that people are willing to "interpret" the coordinates of the linear SVM weight vector as saying something about the relative importance of features. So maybe if you fit lots of SVMs using the same features, it could be meaningful to cluster them?